# Unable to login using Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-login

This is my login view

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get['username']
        password = request.POST.get['password']

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            form = login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f' welcome {username} !!')
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.info(request, f'Unable to Login now')

    form = AuthenticationForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, "BizzyCardApp/log-in.html", context)
```

and this is the log-in.html file

```
{% extends "BizzyCardApp/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="container center oswald" id="grad"  style="border-radius: 10%; width: 300px;">  
    <br>
    <form>
    <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive container">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div>
                    <p>{{ field.label }}: <br> {{ field }}</p> 
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <small style="color: red">{{ error }}</small>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </form> 
          </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light center text-center">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="/sign-up/" class="link-dark">
          Don't have an account? Sign Up
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Once I hit the Submit button, it's supposed to redirect me to the index page but all that happens is that the GET request is done but there is no response from the backend to redirect. It just stays on the same page and the URL changes to

http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=0rkrC5wOe8LDQc9x0s0Zdag45PXRZixJAYaQns3dod58QhUL6OdmTEvZMYdRNTfq&username=tushar&password=abcd123*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the answer. The method for the  tag wasn't given as POST.

The tag was just  and not

The backend kept on getting GET requests instead and that's why the code wasn't working.

This is the Login method code I'm using now

```
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None:
            form = auth_login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f' welcome {username} !!')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.info(request, f'account done not exit plz sign in')
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'BizzyCardApp/log-in.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this login view:

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/index/')
    if request.method=='GET':
        form = loginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            user=authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                              password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user:
                print('user',user)
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/index/')
            else:
                print('Not authenticated')
    elif request.method=='GET':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/index/')
        form=loginForm()
    return render(request,'users/login.html',{'form':form})
```

In forms.py:

Add this:

```
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active or not user.is_validated:
            raise forms.ValidationError('There was a problem with your login.', code='invalid_login')
```

And in login view, change AuthenticationForm to CustomAuthenticationForm. And import it in login view using below code.

```
from .form import CustomAuthenticationForm
```

Comment: loginForm is giving me an error. Where did you import that from?

Comment: what kind of error

Comment: NameError at /login/
name 'loginForm' is not defined

Comment: add your login form there. I think your login form is AuthenticationForm(). Add this form only

Comment: Yeah but if i give AuthenticationForm() nothing happens, I get the same error all over again

Comment: make sure you imported correctly that form

Comment: from .forms import AuthenticationForm  import like this

Comment: I imported it from  "from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm"

Comment: again same error you are getting?

Comment: yeah, nothing happens when I submit the form. The GET request is shown on the backend but nothing happens.

Comment: Still doesn't work :|

Comment: If this is not work then use inbuilt login and try if this work

Comment: are you trying to log without registering the user?

Comment: No, user has been registered.